# Reuse Deleted Aura Component Name

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events

While doing a trailhead superbadge I created a component event named "FormSubmit".
After the fact, I noticed that the specific phrasing on trailhead was "formsubmit" so I deleted the component event thinking I could just recreate it using the correct case. Nope. Since superbadge step checking is very specific I know I cannot proceed in this org without the appropriately named event. Is there a way to flush the deleted component event out so I can recreate or maybe a way to undelete it and try my luck with the incorrect case?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to reuse the name, so long as it was not uploaded as a managed package component. Are you sure the file has been deleted?

Comment: It worked. Just had to wait a few minutes. I initially tried to recreate it immediately after I deleted the event. In the time it took me to type up this question and do some browsing around stack exchange something on the backend changed to allow it.

Comment: @rStrunk You should add your comments as an answer and mark it as accepted, so that at least whoever has the same scenario would know what to look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, while deleting lightning components/events using the developer console, the component can appear to be deleted in the console while it has not yet been deleted from the server. Just waiting a while did the trick.